# Devise Omniauth-Facebook "uninitialized constant OmniAuth"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm trying to setup Omniauth-Facebook testing integration with rspec. I'm having trouble finding good documentation for rspec beginners on this, so it's possible I am doing something wrong. I'm getting this error when trying to run my spec file:

```
/home/nitrous/workspace/spell-hub/spec/spec_helper.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant OmniAuth (NameError)
        from /home/nitrous/workspace/spell-hub/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core.rb:97:in `configure'
        from /home/nitrous/workspace/spell-hub/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/nitrous/workspace/spell-hub/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in `require'
        from /home/nitrous/workspace/spell-hub/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in `block in requires='
        from /home/nitrous/workspace/spell-hub/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in `each'
        from /home/nitrous/workspace/spell-hub/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in `requires='
```

In my spec_helper.rb:

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook,
    { :provider => 'facebook',
      :uid => '1234567',
      :info => { :first_name => 'Jonathan', :name=> 'Jonathan', :email => 'jon@jak.com', :image => 'http://graph.facebook.com/1234567/picture?type=square'},
      :credentials => {
        :expires_at => 1351270850,
        :token=> 'AAADzk0b791YBAHCNhBI3n6ScmWvuXTY4yIUqXr9WiZCg1R808RYzaHxsHnrbn62IwrIgZCfSBZAVIP6ptF41nm8YtRtZCeBbxbbz1mF8RQZDZD'
        } 
      }
    )

  config.include Capybara::DSL
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new__config_option_to_disable_rspeccore_monkey_patching
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

In spec/integrations/omniauth_sessions_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "omniauth facebook", :type => :request do
  it "should have a return UID of 1234567" do
    visit 'users/auth/facebook'
    request.env["omniauth.auth"][:uid].should == '1234567'
  end
end
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to put `require 'omniauth'` in spec_helper.rb for anyone who has this issue in the future.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't do it for me.